# ! Argument of \caption@@@withoptargs has an extra }. error. aip-cp doc class using miktex. It compiles in overleaf

Tags: floats, eps

```
\documentclass{aip-cp}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{caption}


%Added my self
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigstrut}

\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{colordvi}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[framed,numbered]{matlab-prettifier}

\usepackage{filecontents} % to generate an external file from this tex file
\begin{document}

\title{title}% Force line breaks with \\




\maketitle



\begin{abstract}


\maketitle

%\section{\label{sec1:level1} The PN distribution}
\section{\label{sec1:level1} Introduction}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{fig_2}
\caption{\label{fig1:sec1} value.}
\end{figure}


\maketitle

\begin{thebibliography}{30}


\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: not related to this error but don't use `epsfig` in any document written after 1993, it is designed for legacy compatibilty for documents from the 1980s

Comment: please make a smaller example. I doubt very much that all these packages are needed to reproduce the problem. And add a link to your class, it is not in miktex by default.

Comment: I've never seen a document with 3 `\maketitle`. Usually classes only allow one (but there are exceptions).